# What's the ruling on someone who tells others to stop sinning?

Tags: halal-haram

As-Salamu alaikum brother and sisters, is it obligatory to tell someone who's about to sin or who's sinning to stop sinning? Jazakum Allah khayran...
May Allah guide us, baraka Allahu feena

Answer (score 1):

The person is doing what is required of them in Islam. Yes it is obligatory, in that it is *Fard al-Kifayah*.

> ولتكن منكم أمة يدعون إلى الخير ويأمرون بالمعروف **وينهون عن المنكر** وأولئك هم المفلحون
>
> And let there be [arising] from you a nation inviting to [all that is] good, enjoining what is right and **forbidding what is wrong**, and those will be the successful.
>
> <sup>— [Quran 3:104](http://quran.com/3/104)</sup>

> من رأى منكم منكرا فليغيره بيده فإن لم يستطع فبلسانه فإن لم يستطع فبقلبه وذلك أضعف الإيمان
>
> Whoever among you sees an evil action, let him change it with his hand; if he cannot, then with his tongue; and if he cannot, then with his heart and that is the weakest
>   of faith.
>
> <sup>— [Sahih Muslim , كتاب الإيمان](https://sunnah.com/muslim/1/84)</sup>